# htaccess rewrite to index.php in variable directory (cms directory)

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I´m having the following problem:
I´d like to build a script which should work **in every directory, regardless wheter root-directory or subdirectory**. So the most important thing is, that I have a .htaccess-file which will **redirect all requests to the index.php** in the directory where the script was installed. The redirect is simple, there are plenty of tutorials. But the problem is that I don't know the path in which the script was installed. I don't know if it's a subdirectory or root-directory. The only solution I see is to make a install.php which will modify the htaccess with the correct paths. But are there better solutions?

**Thank you!**

Update:
Since there is apparently misunderstandings with my question, I will give you an example. Let's say my project contains only one index.php and a .htaccess-file. The .htaccess-file should redirect all requests to the index.php. That is very simple, **BUT:** the .htaccess-file does not know in which directory it will be called, so it could be the user installed the project in /xyz/ but also in the root directory /. If I request xyz/abc/123/echo/world/ the .htaccess-file does not know in which of this directories the index.php is for the redirect, it only knows that it should redirect to the index.php of the root of the script. So my solution would be to make a install.php and change the .htaccess-file with the correct paths, but aren't there better solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?/)?[^/]+$ /$1/index.php [L]
```

This will rewrite every request that is not a valid file/directory to `index.php` of that sub-directory.

**EDIT:** If you want to place this in a `/anydir/` then use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(.*?/)(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . %{ENV:BASE}index.php [L]
```

Comment: You have misunderstood my question. Your script redirects to a index.php inside the requested directory. So if I request /directory/test/ your script would call /directory/test/index.php but that is wrong! My script will only contain **one index.php** in a unknown directory. Please see the edit in my post for further informations.

Comment: You probably haven't clarified your requirements. How will any rule / code know where that unknown directory is?

Comment: That is the problem. And my question is, if there are better solutions than to define this specific directory within an installation-process. Many CMS does have the same problem, how do they handle it?

Comment: No CMS has this problem, you are either mistaken OR mean somethign else by `unknown directory` term. All CMS frameworks place their main .htaccess in a well known directory OR DocumentRoot which is accessible by web.

Comment: I can download for example Typo3 and install it into a directory of my choice, so it is available under for example /mychoice/ . So the mod_rewrite in the .htaccess works perfectly. But how did they made the trick? If I require example.com/mychoice/mypage/subpage/ the .htacces-file does not know if it was called within the root-directory or within the /mychoice/ directory, as long I do not provide this information.

Comment: The only possible solution I see is that I can say "call the index.php in the same server-directory as this .htaccess-file on every request". Because the script does not know in which frontend-route this index.php is

Comment: When you install it in `/mychoice/` you also place .htaccess in `/mychoice/` and access it using `http://domain.com/mychoice/` so nothing remains unknown

Comment: That is correct. My script should redirect all request to the index.php in the same directory, so /mychoice/index.php . You know that you require .htaccess in /mychoice/ but the .htaccess does not know in which directory it was called. It can think it is in the root directory and redirects to /index.php. My problem is, that I have to build the path for the redirect to the index.php in which the .htaccess is. With which informations do I know the correct path?

Comment: I do not want to say lets redirect to /mychoice/index.php I want to say "lets redirect to the index.php in the directory, in which the current .htaccess is". that would be /mychoice/

Comment: If you look at rule I provided it does exactly that. It rewrites `/mychoice/anything` to `/mychoice/index.php` without you specifying `/mychoice/` anywhere in the the rule.

Comment: I put the .htaccess with your code inside the directory /dir/ and tested it with: domain.com/dir/test/, and it redirects to the domain.com/index.php internal! /dir/test/hello/ will give a 404 not found.. 
maybe we get us wrong?

Comment: That means you didn't read my answer correctly. My 1st line says: `Place this rule in your root .htaccess` If you want to place in subdir then I will update my answer with another alternative.

Comment: Thank you so much! Works like a charm, even in the root-directory! There is only one thing I need to understand: The two lines to define ENV BASE. Do you have a link for a good tutorial/explanation?

Comment: Actually I don't have good tutorial on that one but that trick compares `REQUEST_URI` variable (which is complete path) with the URI matched by `RewriteRule` (which is relative to current path) and gets differential in `%{ENV:BASE}` variable.